# How To Provide Credentials To Google's LoggingAppender via logback.xml?

Tags: java, logback, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging, logback-classic

I have a `logback.xml` configuration with an appender like this:

```
<appender name="cloud" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
    <projectId>myproject</projectId>
    <credentialsFile>src/jvmMain/resources/secrets/logging-access.json</credentialsFile>
    <log>projects/myproject/logs/backend</log>
    <flushLevel>WARN</flushLevel>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
</appender>
```

This works great when I'm running via the IDE which can find the `credentialsFile` at its original location on the filesystem.

However, once I build the app, the resources are compiled in to the jars somewhere instead of being raw files.  (At least, I can't find the raw files anywhere.)

*How can I tell `logback.xml` to fetch the credentials from the compiled resources?*

Comment: Have you deployed your app on Google Cloud Run?

Comment: You rarely need a service account JSON file. Most of the time it works without (thanks to ADC mechanism). Have a try without that tag, it should magically work out of the box!

Comment: Yeah, cloud-run crashes with SEGV at startup when this appender is active.  Currently trying to reproduce the crash locally which led to this.  (Crash may or may not be related to having credentials but it's definitely the appender.)

Comment: The SEGV was due to an [incompatibility with Alpine Linux](https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging-logback/issues/1055) and not related to the credentials in any way.  Logging works without them from Cloud-Run.  However, it would still be useful to know, for testing reasons, if it is possible to load them from a Java resource.